# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server - not correct resolution on terminal

Tags: server, intel-graphics, display-resolution

So I have an DELL monitor. The documentation for the monitor says that the optimum resolution using their supplied HDMI cable is 2560x1440@60Hz. When I boot into Windows, I  can get that resolution. But no matter what I try, I can't get that resolution in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server.

I am using DELL OptiPlex 7070 with i5-9500 and Intel graphics card (Intel UHD Graphics 630).

When I run Grub, I have correct resolution. Then by booting into Linux, I have not correct resolution (2048x1152) on terminal. In Linux, I only use text mode.

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server generally outputs at 800x600, 1024x768, or something similar because people (generally) connect to it over SSH. This allows the server to allocate less memory for video processing.

That said, you can update this relatively easily by making a change in the GRUB configuration file. Here's how:

0. Log in to the server (or connect via SSH)
1. Edit the GRUB configuration file:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/default/grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Add a `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` definition to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=2560x1440
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** You cannot set the refresh rate. This will be limited to 30fps.</sup>
3. Save the file and exit.
4. Update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Restart the server.

That's all there is to it. If you would like to have more graphic options, such as changing the font, anti-aliasing, and the like, you will probably want to use Ubuntu Desktop and install the various server components that you might need.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I still have resolution 2048x1152 .